# How to hide status bar (system tray) in ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: unity, system-tray

How to make system tray to auto-hide just like you can unity launcher?
I haven't found any questions about, so I think this wouldn't be easy, but maybe there is some workaround way?

I'd like to have as much screen real estate as possible.
I know about full screen mode - it's not what I want, because If I would display another window in this mode it still shows system tray.

Comment: You want to remove the gnome-panel then?

Comment: What do you call gnome panel? I'm talking about the thing with clock, sound, wifi icon etc.